# wrong column type in "table" for column "xy" Found: int8, expected: int4

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I'm using hibernate with postgres/postgis.
As I switched the Hibernate property "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" from "update" to validate I got this exception:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in history for column type_id. Found: int8, expected: int4

First i thought that hibernate needs each reference to another table to be int8. I chose to change the column type_id to bigint with no success. I'm out of ideas. Can somebody help?

My entities are structured this way:

```
@Entity
public class History{       
  @Id
  protected Integer id;
  private Date created_on;
  private Date timestamp;
  @ManyToOne
  private DataType type;
  private Double value;
}
@Entity
public class DataType{      
   @Id
   private Integer id;
   private String cname;
   private Date created_on;
   private String cunit;
 }
```

These are the table definitions in the db:

History

```
    Column |            Type             | Modifiers                            
------------+-----------------------------+-----------------
id         | integer                     | not null default                          nextval('history_id_seq'::regclass)
created_on | timestamp without time zone | 
timestamp  | timestamp without time zone | 
value      | double precision            | 
type_id    | bigint                      | not null
Indexes:
"pk_history" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Foreign-key constraints:
"fk_history" FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id)
```

Type

```
Column      |            Type             | Modifiers 
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------
id          | bigint                      | not null
cname       | character varying(255)      | 
created_on  | timestamp without time zone | 
cunit       | character varying(255)      | 

Indexes:
"type_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
TABLE "history" CONSTRAINT "fk_history" FOREIGN KEY (type_id) REFERENCES type(id)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748130/how-to-map-postgres-int8-to-java-entity-using-hibernate

Comment: How did you defined your tables? Java's `int` (boxed in `Integer`) has 4 bytes, just like PostgreSQL's `integer` (= `int`, `int4`, `serial`'s storage). But `bigint` (= `int8`, `bigserial`'s storage) has 8 bytes, which should be mapped to Java's `long`.

Comment: Does the first comment relate to my case? How? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17748130/how-to-map-postgres-int8-to-java-entity-using-hibernate