# JPA schema validation with PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA (hibernate) with Postgres database, my hibernate database configuration are as below:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","validate");
```

I have a table with property `created_by_user_id`

```
CREATE TABLE dppm_main.user_account_profile
( ....//other columns
  created_by_user_id integer
)
```

Mapped to JPA entity as below:

```
@Column(name = "created_by_user_id")
private Long createdByUserId;
```

While doing schema validation, I am getting following error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column 
type encountered in column [created_by_user_id] in table [user_account_profile];
 **found [int4 (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [int8 (Types#BIGINT)]**
```

How can I fix it? I am having this issue in many places so is it possible to fix it by extending `PostgreSQL82Dialect` instead of **columnDefinition**.

Comment: Very similar to [wrong column type in “table” for column Found: int8, expected: int4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27230426/wrong-column-type-in-table-for-column-xy-found-int8-expected-int4)

Comment: I know nothing about JPA, but the error message suggests that it expects the column to be defined as `bigint` because your JPA entity uses `Long`. Try to either use `Integer` in the JPA entity or `bigint` in the table definition.

Comment: @suraj bahi Where you able to solve it? I am facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 10):

The exception is clearly speaking about types mismatch between Java types and Postgres types.

I didn't understand clearly what is your type in Postgres, so I'll point a few types conversions:

**Postgres**: `smallint` **to Java** --> `java.lang.Short`

**Postgres**: `integer` **to Java** --> `java.lang.Integer`

**Postgres**: `bigint` **to Java** --> `java.lang.Long`

With that being said, just change from:

```
@Column(name = "created_by_user_id")
private Long createdByUserId;
```

To:

```
@Column(name = "created_by_user_id")
private Integer createdByUserId;
```

Comment: Is not it ?
**Postgres**: `smallint` **to Java** --> `short`