# Mapping array with Hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, jpa

Can you please help me to map this class using Hibernate?

```
public class MyClass{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private int[] values;
    ...
}
```

I'm using PostgreSQL and the column type in the table is integer[]
How my array should be mapped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have never mapped arrays to hibernate. I always use collections. So, I have slightly changed you class:

```
public class MyClass{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> values;

    @Id
    // this is only if your id is really auto generated
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO) 
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }   
    ...
```

Comment: It doesn't work. `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class`

Comment: how come this answer has been accepted ? You have to use @ElementCollection or create a custom type.

Comment: When using OneToMany you can only use list with other entities. So primatives wont work. As @AleksBenMaza said use ElementCollection with non mapped elements

Comment: @AlexR I need to map my multidimensional double array? what to do please suggest.

Answer (score 18):

Hibernate (and JPA) can't directly map the PostgreSQL array type. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate) for how to proceed if you really need to retain your database structure as it is. [This thread](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=946973) has an example of the required custom type.

If you can change your schema, you can let hibernate create an additional table to handle the collection - `List<Integer>`. Then, depending on the version of hibernate you are using:

- JPA 2.0 compliant - use [`@ElementCollection`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ElementCollection.html)
- JPA 1.0 compliant - use [`@CollectionOfElements`](https://web.archive.org/web/20101126125212/http://docs.jboss.org:80/hibernate/stable/core/api/org/hibernate/annotations/CollectionOfElements.html)

Comment: Will those annotations create a one-to-many association automatically?

Answer (score 10):

### Maven dependency

The first thing you need to do is to set up the following [Hypersistence Utils](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hypersistence-utils) Maven dependency in your project `pom.xml` configuration file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62</artifactId>
    <version>${hypersistence-utils.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

### PostgreSQl ARRAY columns

Assuming you have this table in your PostgreSQL database:

```
create table event (
    id int8 not null, 
    version int4, 
    sensor_names text[], 
    sensor_values integer[], 
    primary key (id)
)
```

And you want to map it like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Event")
@Table(name = "event")
public class Event {

    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Type(StringArrayType.class)
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_names", 
        columnDefinition = "text[]"
    )
    private String[] sensorNames;
 
    @Type(IntArrayType.class)
    @Column(
        name = "sensor_values", 
        columnDefinition = "integer[]"
    )
    private int[] sensorValues;
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

The `StringArrayType` and `IntArrayType` are classes offered by the Hypersistence Utils project.

### Testing time

Now, when you insert a couple of entities:

```
Event nullEvent = new Event();
nullEvent.setId(0L);
entityManager.persist(nullEvent);
 
Event event = new Event();
event.setId(1L);
event.setSensorNames(
    new String[] {
        "Temperature", 
        "Pressure"
    }
);
event.setSensorValues( 
    new int[] {
        12, 
        756
    } 
);
entityManager.persist(event);
```

Hibernate is going to generate the following SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO event (
    version, 
    sensor_names, 
    sensor_values, 
    id
) 
VALUES (
    0, 
    NULL(ARRAY), 
    NULL(ARRAY), 
    0
)
     
INSERT INTO event (
    version, 
    sensor_names, 
    sensor_values, 
    id
) 
VALUES ( 
    0, 
    {"Temperature","Pressure"}, 
    {"12","756"}, 
    1
)
```

Comment: Your examples work perfectly fine for Insert/Update. Can you give an example to fetch two types of arrays in single query?

Comment: I tried, but I am getting only those values whose properties I set. And I am unable to transform the resultset using sqlresultsetmapping

Comment: Does your library supports Spring-Boot 2.2.4 Release? When I upgrade it,  I am getting this exception `Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.Module: Provider com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule not found
`

Answer (score 8):

Hibernate can map only the primitive types. Check under the org.hibernate.type folder of hibernate jar package. int array is not one of them. So you would have to write a custom type that can implement the UserType interface.

```
public class MyClass{
     private Long id;
     private String name;
     private Integer[] values;

     @Type(type = "com.usertype.IntArrayUserType")
     public Integer[] getValues(){
         return values;
     }

     public void setValues(Integer[] values){
         this.values = values;
     }
 }
```

IntArrayUserType.class

```
package com.usertype.IntArrayUserType;

public class IntArrayUserType implements UserType {

protected static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.ARRAY };

@Override
public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner) throws HibernateException {
    return this.deepCopy(cached);
}

@Override
public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value;
}

@Override
public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return (Integer[]) this.deepCopy(value);
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {

    if (x == null) {
        return y == null;
    }
    return x.equals(y);
}

@Override
public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    return x.hashCode();
}

@Override
public boolean isMutable() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, SessionImplementor session, Object owner)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (resultSet.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }
    if(resultSet.getArray(names[0]) == null){
        return new Integer[0];
    }

    Array array = resultSet.getArray(names[0]);
    Integer[] javaArray = (Integer[]) array.getArray();
    return javaArray;
}

@Override
public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement statement, Object value, int index, SessionImplementor session)
        throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    Connection connection = statement.getConnection();
    if (value == null) {
        statement.setNull(index, SQL_TYPES[0]);
    } else {
        Integer[] castObject = (Integer[]) value;
        Array array = connection.createArrayOf("integer", castObject);
        statement.setArray(index, array);
    }
}

@Override
public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)       throws HibernateException {
    return original;
}

@Override
public Class<Integer[]> returnedClass() {
    return Integer[].class;
}

@Override
public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return new int[] { Types.ARRAY };
}
```

When you query for the MyClass entity you can add something like this:

```
Type intArrayType = new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom(IntArrayUserType.class);
Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("select values from MyClass")
   .addScalar("values", intArrayType);
List<Integer[]> results = (List<Integer[]>) query.list();
```

Comment: Do you use this in production? Does this work for you?

Comment: Yes it is working in production. I have copied this snippet from my working code

Answer (score 3):

From Hibernate 6.1 Final, basic arrays and collections may now be mapped to database ARRAY types if possible, or alternatively JSON/XML types.

https://in.relation.to/2022/06/14/orm-61-final/

Answer (score 1):

Update to the given answers:

With Hibernate 6.x mapping an array is as simple as:

```java
    import org.hibernate.annotations.Array;


    @Array(length = 12)
    public double[] monthlyPayments = new double[12];
```

And if you're using Liquibase, then you can define this column as follows:

```xml
<column name="monthlyPayments" type="float[12]" />
```

This will map into a float[12] array in PostgreSql.