# Javax.persistence with @Entity bean saving int[] as bytea (postgres)

Tags: java, jpa, jdbc, types, persistence

In my current project i have an @Entity bean, with, among others, an int[] field, which should match an integer[] field in my postgres database.
However, upon persisting my object i get an exception like this:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "drawset_basedata" is of type integer[] but expression is of type bytea
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO drawset (drawset_id, drawset_basedata, drawset_created, drawset_data) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
    bind => [null, [B@19701da, null, [B@facd93]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(lotoFlow.Drawset[drawsetId=null])
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:333)
```

I used the debugger and i can see clearly that the baseData proprety is an initialised int[] variable, i don't understand why it arrives as an bytea.
Thanks!

Comment: what provider are you using for your entity manager? can you post your saving code?

Comment: i do getEntityManager().persist(entity); // entity is my persisted bean with all the data and the int[] field, and the entity manager is a javax.persistence.EntityManager

Comment: in fact it seems that there are difficulties with either jpa or hibernate with postgres arrays see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate and JPA do not support PostgreSQL arrays, so your best bet is to normalize your model or run your SQL manually.

While it is true that PostgreSQL handles arrays very well, many other dbs do not.  For this reason one generally does not expect great array support in cross-db frameworks.