# Mapping postgreSQL inetger[] data type to Grails

Tags: postgresql, grails

In my postgreSQL DB i have a field with the data type `int[]` trying to mapp this to a Grails domain class column `Integer[]` the application fails to start:

```
org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

I also tried this:             `//insurance column: 'rs_insurance', sqlType: "integer[]"`

Answer (score 0):

`byte[]` type is working out-of-box and is mapped to a respective `BLOB`-type.

If it's not fine with you, you can serialize your array upon saving and deserialize it upon loading:

```
void setValue( v ) {
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
  baos.withObjectOutputStream{ it.writeObject v }
  blob = baos.toByteArray()
}

def getValue() {
  def out = null
  if( blob ) new ByteArrayInputStream( blob ).withObjectInputStream{ out = it.readObject() }
  out
}
```

Comment: Values from DB (57,58,59,60) were transformed into these values [123, 53, 55, 44, 53, 56, 44, 53, 57, 44, 54, 48, 125] ???

Comment: what did you do? what sql type is your column of?

Comment: Column is type integer[] and value is {57,58,59,60}

Comment: if you are lucky, this might work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate

Comment: `interger[]` is a postgres artefact type and has no analogues in other SQL-dialects

Comment: do you need this field outside the grails application? do you need to be able to search in it?

Comment: I need the field as a member of a domain class inside the grails app. List<Integer> compiles but the values are not there.

Comment: then use serialization approach or create an SQL-custom type to map