# How mapping List<Long> with array_agg?

Tags: java, hibernate

I execute this request @Subselect using Hibernate

SELECT сolumn1,
array_agg(DISTINCT сolumn2::integer)
FROM table GROUP BY сolumn1;

result SQL:

```
 сolumn1 | сolumn2 
------------+---------------------
          1 | {1}                 
          2 | {2,3}               
          3 | {3}
```

My DAO class:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFJBh.png)

```
import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
@Subselect("SELECT сolumn1,\n" +
        "\tarray_agg(DISTINCT сolumn2::integer)\n" +
        "FROM table GROUP BY сolumn1;")
@Immutable
public class Table {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "сolumn1")
    private Long сolumn1;

    @Column(name = "сolumn2")
    private Integer[] сolumn2;
}
```

Now it does not work, an error occurs:

```
message": "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
```

How mapping List with array_agg ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem with deserialization of your `Interger[] column2` . Replace it with a `Collection<Integer>`

That should allow it to map succesfully.

[Mapping array with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate)

Comment: add Collection from java.util.Collection ?

Comment: correct, You'd have to import ```java.util.Collection```. Does the linked question help?

Comment: Unfortunately no, a similar error.

need to use Array or PgArray from import java.sql.Array;

Comment: whats the error when u use collection? You now have to convert the collection to an array whenever you're using it.