# Map PostgreSQL int[] array to List in Java entity

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

Have 1 PostgreSQL table look like following

```
int     id,
int[]   childIds
```

How can I map `childIds` to a `List` in Java entity?

```
class A {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column
       private int id;

       @Type(type = "int-array")   
       @Column(name = "childIds")
       private List<Integer> childIds;
}
```

Got following error when trying to build the code

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : int-array
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mapping array with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate)