# Getting error while passing short[] to function using jpa

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, short

I have created a function as below :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo(ids SMALLINT[])
RETURNS TABLE (processkey bigint)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY SELECT b.processkey FROM your_table b WHERE id_column = ANY(ids);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

In java repository class I create below method :

```
List<Object[]> getData(short[] ids) {
    String strq="select * from demo(:ids)";
    Query q=entitymanager.createNativeQuery(strq);
    q.setParameter("ids",ids);
    return  q.getResultList();
}
```

In my controller :

```java
short[] requestid= new short[]{1,2};
List<Object[]>response=repo.getData(requestid);
System.out.println(response);
```

But while executing this it gives error as
Bytea cannot cast to smallint .
I don't know why am getting this error

```
Error.o.h.e.SqlExecptionHelper-Error : cannot cast type bytea to smallint , position 26 , ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver- javax.persistrnce.PersistenceException: SqlGrammerException : could not extract Resultset
```

Comment: I don't see any error in the code can you post your stacktrace if it is possible?

Comment: Also why does it assume that it is a byte data? maybe you need to solve that part.

Comment: Error.o.h.e.SqlExecptionHelper-Error : cannot cast type bytea to smallint , position 26 , ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver- javax.persistrnce.PersistenceException: SqlGrammerException : could not extract Resultset

Comment: Strange. There is no return statement in your `getData` method. Also `crrateNativeQuery` looks suspicious. Did you post actual code?

Comment: It does have.i forget to add in here.

Comment: Especially List<Object[]>response is a little bit tricky. How did you parse it to Object?

Comment: There are some big integers that needs to be returned but I can not see conversion part?

Comment: Is there any scenario where `ids` can be null?

Comment: no way it is initialized new short[]{1,2};

Comment: Your error is because Hibernate does not map properly your `short[]` (java) into a `smallint[]` (postgresql): you probably have to fiddle with the configuration or try your chance with a `List<Short>` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332467/mapping-array-with-hibernate

Comment: I have tried using criteria query,it works well with short[] then why native does not work. ?