# ERROR: column "xxxxxxx" is of type character varying[] but expression is of type bytea

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

I am getting Error in Spring and using db postgres

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "XXXXXXXXXX" is of type 
                                       character varying[] but expression is of type bytea
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

My POJO have data_member like:

```
@Column(name = "xxxxxxx")
private String[] xxxxxxx;
```

Comment: Provide more details. If convenient put some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mapping a postgres array with hibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgres-array-with-hibernate)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement hibernate *UserType* interface, 
and then add `@Type` annotation to your attribute.

*Example:*

```
@Column(name = "xxxxxxx")
@Type(type = "xx.xxx.xxx.YourImplementationOfUserType")
private String[] xxxxxxx;
```