# How to map a List<String> with Hibernate/JPA WITHOUT an extra join table?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

The question I'm asking is pretty simple but seemingly impossible to find an answer to.  I'm using Spring Data JPA and I have a JDBC/JPA `DataSource` (which is PostgreSQL, but that shouldn't matter), which is preloaded with data and I simply am trying to read from it.

How do I construct my POJO so that I can have a `List<String>` field that doesn't require an extra join table?  Here is an example entity class I have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pojo", schema = "pojoschema")
public class POJO {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "a_string", columnDefinition = "text")
  private String aString;

  @Column(name = "strings", columnDefinition = "text[]")
  @ElementCollection
  private List<String> strings;

  // getters/setters
}
```

Doing this I get a `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "pojo_strings" does not exist`.

Why does hibernate think that the `String`s I want are in another table? How do I fix this behavior? I'm simply trying to map a PostgreSQL `text[]` column back to a `List<String>` in a POJO via JPA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/mapping-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate

Comment: Thanks, that's really unfortunate then...

Answer (score 6):

The approach in these cases is to use jpa's `AttributeConverter` like this:

```
@Converter
public class StringToListConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<String>, String> {

  @Override
  public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<String> list) {
    if(list == null) return "";
    return String.join(",", list); 
  }

  @Override
  public List<String> convertToEntityAttribute(String joined) {
    if(joined == null) return new ArrayList<>();
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(joined.split(",")));
  }
}
```

And use the annotation `Converter` in your entity field:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pojo", schema = "pojoschema")
public class POJO {
  @Id
  @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
  private String id;

  @Column(name = "a_string", columnDefinition = "text")
  private String aString;

  @Column(name = "strings")
  @Convert(converter = StringToListConverter.class)
  private List<String> strings;

  // getters/setters
}
```

Comment: My database column isn't a single `text` field.  Would this work if the column in the database is `text[]`?

Comment: Ofc, in this case you can/should use `text` datatype on db side.

Comment: Thanks, that did work.  I saw your solution somewhere else, but assumed the mapping from `text[]` to `String` wouldn't work.  Just seems like extra work I shouldn't have to do when using an ORM :/

Comment: ORMs do a tremendous job to facilitate the mapping of tables in objects but there are also some cases that need to be handled manually (at a point).

Comment: Definitely agree, this just seems like a trivial case though.