# Is there a way to map a postgres array to a list without creating an additional table?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I start my application creating a database model. And I cannot understand if there is any way in hibernate-jpa to save a List of strings as an array.

If I simply try to save my

`List<String> someLines;`

as sql

`some_lines text[]`

I get an error that array cannot be represented as a List.

If I put an annotation `@ElementCollection` like

```
@ElementCollection
List<String> someLines;
```

another table `some_elements` is expected. The same happens If I additionally put an annotation `@Column`:

```
@Column(name = "some_lines")
@ElementCollection
List<String> someLines;
```

How do you usually save a simple List in DB (without creating an additional table)?

Comment: Usually a "list" **is** stored in a separate table - it's the textbook example of normalizing a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: No, but you can store an array of strings and some other basic types with an extension you can add to your project dependencies.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name there are different collections. some of them don't need a separate table. good textbooks usually give many different examples.

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1647583/1854103