# How to map Java/Kotlin string array and Postgres SQL array with JPA and hibernate

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I have a field in Postgres in array type:

```
 categories    | text[]         |           |          |
```

How can I declare the field in the entity class?

I have tried below in `Product.kt` file but it throws error `[ERROR]:ERROR: relation "product_categories" does not exist`

```
@ElementCollection
@Column(name = "categories")
var categories: List<String>? = emptyList()
```

My purpose is to save the string array as one field of the entity, I am not trying to do anything related "One to Many".

If you know any Java version solution and it works, I will accept the answer as well. Thanks

Comment: For anyone who need the Kotlin version, I have posted all details as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work with `@ElementCollection` as it will always try to use another table. What you need is a custom type instead. For this you'll need this dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate-types.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

then you can define your own types:

```kotlin
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType

@TypeDefs({
    @TypeDef(
        name = "string-array", 
        typeClass = StringArrayType.class
    )
})
@Entity
class YourEntity {

    @Type( type = "string-array" )
    @Column(
        name = "categories", 
        columnDefinition = "character varying[]"
    )
    var categories: Array<String>;
}
```

I haven't tried this with a `List` though, as this maps to an `Array`. More info in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/how-to-map-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate) answer.

Comment: Thank you Adam. It is the right direction and I have converted to Kotlin version and everything works fine!

Answer (score 4):

Adam's answer works for projects written in Java. As my project is written in Kotlin, I share my version below and hope it helps and people can use it right away other than spending time to convert:

Useful resource: [How to map Java and SQL arrays with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-java-and-sql-arrays-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Postgres:

```
alter table product add column categories text[];
```

Gradle:

```
implementation("com.vladmihalcea:hibernate-types-52:2.10.0")
```

Product.kt

```
import com.vladmihalcea.hibernate.type.array.StringArrayType
import org.hibernate.annotations.*
import javax.persistence.*
import javax.persistence.Entity


@TypeDefs(
    TypeDef(name = "string-array", typeClass = StringArrayType::class)
)
@Entity
class Product(
        var name: String,

        @Type(type = "string-array")
        @Column(name = "categories", columnDefinition = "text[]")
        var categories: Array<String>? = arrayOf(),
)
```

There're 2 differences between Java and Kotlin:

1. The array type in Kotlin is Array<String> other than String[], I tried List<String> as well but it didn't work.
2. TypeDefs,TypeDef is different, no @ sign.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the one mentioned by Haifeng, for Kotlin, there is another option to use `ListArrayType` instead of `StringArrayType` so you do not need to care about converting list to array.

I met another issue retrieving the data, I had `java.lang.ArrayStoreException: arraycopy: type mismatch: can not copy [Ljava.lang.String;[] into java.lang.String[]\n`. Just for those who may also encounter this, my issue was the data storing in DB is not array but array of array.