# ERROR: column "bookedseat" is of type text[] but expression is of type bytea

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot

I have a column named `bookedseat` which is of type `String[]`:

```
@Column(name="bookedseat")
private String[] bookedseat;
```

I also defined a constructor, and getter and setter methods, but I get the following error:

```
ERROR: column "bookedseat" is of type text[] but expression is of type bytea
```

Comment: maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/q/65118234/15603477 can help you.

Comment: @Rishi: How was this solved ?