# CockroachDB Array type to Java Type

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cockroachdb

I am new to both CockroachDb and Hibernate/JPA. I am trying to understand how to map Array types in CockroachDb to a java type in an entity class. I see in the hibernate docs some information about types and casts https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/mapping-types.html . There is no information about CockroachDb's Array type here, does this mean that it is not supported yet in JPA/Hibernate?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Since CockroachDB is wire format compatible with Postgres, this answer _may_ be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/how-to-map-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate

I say "may" because I am not a Java dev.