# Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DdlType.getTypeName(org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.Size)"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I'm Migrating from Java-11 to Java-17 and Spring Boot-3. Using Postgres as a database. Using Hibernate 6+. Updated annotation accordingly to Hibernate 6 like jakarta.persistence.*

Getting error while saving Object.

**Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.DdlType.getTypeName(org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.Size)" because the return value of "org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.spi.DdlTypeRegistry.getDescriptor(int)" is null**

My Model class:

```
 @Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "mapping")
@Converts({
        @Convert(
                attributeName = "int-array",
                converter = IntArrayType.class
        ),
        @Convert(
                attributeName = "string-array",
                converter = StringArrayType.class
        )
})
public class Mapping {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name_id")
    private String nameID;

    @Column(name = "pyouuu")
    private Integer pyouuu;

    @Column(name = "kocc")
    private Integer kocc;

    @Basic
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.ARRAY)
    @Column(
            name = "intvalues",
            columnDefinition = "integer[]"
    )
    private Integer[] intvalues;

    @Basic
    @JdbcTypeCode(SqlTypes.ARRAY)
    @Column(
            name = "content",
            columnDefinition = "text[]"
    )
    private String[] content;

    @Column(name = "relevance_id")
    private Integer relevanceId;

}
```

Saving Mapping Object -

```
  @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Spring Boot -3 ");
         String strArr[] = new String[]{"ABC","IPFFGH","APPLE"};
         Integer intArr[] = new Integer[]{397,221,1010};
        Mapping mapping = new Mapping();
                mapping.setKocc(1112);
                mapping.setPyouuu(554);
                mapping.setRelevanceId(0002147);
                mapping.setContent(strArr);
                mapping.setIntValues(intArr);
                mapping.setNameID("IPF-gss");

        repository.save(mapping);
        System.out.println("Saved....!");

    }
```

MappingRepository -

```
import com.app.com.model.Mapping;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface MappingRepository extends JpaRepository<Mapping,Long> {
}
```

My app.prop file

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/angad?currentSchema=test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Welcome@123
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

My build.gradle file

dependencies {

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:6.1.3")
implementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:6.1.3")
implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
implementation 'org.json:json:20230227'
implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3'
implementation 'org.redisson:redisson:3.19.0'
implementation 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.6.0'
implementation "com.h2database:h2:2.2.220"
implementation 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'

testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

}

Any suggestions really appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You say you get an error while saving an object, but your question does not contain any code that saves an object. The problem is likely related to the piece of code that saves the object. To find out where that is, you might want to look at the stack trace that comes along with the error. Then the idea is that you do not post all of your code but only the part of the code that seems relevant to the question.

Comment: @Max I added the code

Comment: Your last edit was from before my comment. Your code does not contain logic that saves an object.

Comment: @MaxMeijer Please check now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to save a database Array of integers using Hibernate. This is not possible without some additional code. To see how you would be able to do this, have a look at the answers to this question: [How to map a PostgreSQL array with Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/how-to-map-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate)

Comment: I'm using this dependency - implementation 'io.hypersistence:hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62:3.5.3' will provide the int & string [] type

Comment: Have you tried changing your code to be more like the answer I linked? So using typedefs and actually using your int-array and string-array as the types of the arrays?