column "a" is of type integer[] but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression
I created a 2d int array (INT[][]) in postgres. It is possible to store values through Dbeaver but when I try to update the value from Kotlin, Quarkus, Hibernate it throws an error.
This is the query,
`update a set a='{{0,0},{0,0}}' where id=100 (the type of a is INT[][])`

`(Panache Repository) aRepository.update("update aEntity set a='{{0,0},{0,0}}' where id=100")`

This is the complete stacktrace,
 `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "a" is of type integer[] but expression is of type character varying Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. Position: 23 at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2733) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2420) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:372) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:517) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:434) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194) at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:155) at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:90) at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:194) ... 51 more

Converter class,
class MultiDIntArrayConverter : AttributeConverter<Array<IntArray>, String> {

override fun convertToDatabaseColumn(p0: Array<IntArray>?): String {
    if (p0 == null) {
        return ""
    }
    return p0.contentDeepToString().replace("[", "{").replace("]", "}").replace(" ", "")
}

Any help would be appreciated.
It is not possible to store/change values through hibernate with kotlin. There are some examples with java but they can not be applied to kotlin and contains outdated libraries.

Looks like the type adaption is working in the code and '{{0,0},{0,0}}' is being seen as string instead of as an array. The Postgres  JDBC driver has this Arrays. For Hibernate see this SO question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647583/how-to-map-a-postgresql-array-with-hibernate

Unfortunately, com.vladmihalcea library is outdated. I wanted to use the newest versions of hibernate-orm which suggests implementing AttributeConverter instead of Usertype. I already implemented an attribute converter but it has the same problem. To be more clear I wanted to show you the repository update method only. Otherwise you are right, I already implemented a converter but the error is the same there.
